# Convex optimization problem to quadratic programming problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

Briefly, have the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 0}^n a_i \ (max [ F_i( \bar x ), 0 ] )^2 \rightarrow  min, \\\\
s.t.\\\\
A \bar x \leq b
\end{equation}
where $ F( \bar x ) $ is a linear function, $a_i \gt 0$, $n$ is huge comparing to the size of $x$.

It is possible to write an equal Quadratic Programming problem, such as

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \ ( G_i )^2 \rightarrow min \\\\
s.t. \\\\
G_i \geq {\bf 0}, \quad i = 0..n \\\\
G_i \geq F_i( \bar x ) \quad i = 0..n \\\\
A \bar x \leq b
$$

which can be solved very efficiently with an appropriate numerical method.

Unfortunately in my particular case such conversion doesn't work: it adds a lot of new restrictions, and that appropriate numerical method doesn't converge.

I tried to figure out another equal QPP, which adds fewer new constraints, but nothing came across my mind. Is there another way?

Comment: If you are talking about $\min[\max(F( \bar x), 0)]^2$ where $\bar{x}$ is unconstrained, you don't need any software to do it: as $F$ is linear, the answer is zero, and global minimum is attained at $\bar{x}=0$. If there are additional constraints, you may try to specify them in your question.

Comment: @user1551 there are standart linear constraints. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer. I just want to say that your optimization problem can be converted into a *linear* programming problem:

> $\min F(\bar{x})$ subject to $A\bar{x}\le b$.

If the minimum found is $m$ and the minimizer is $x_0$, then the minimum for your original problem is $\max(m,0)^2$ and the minimizer is $x_0$.

Reason: If $F(x_0)=m<0$, then $\max(F(x_0), 0)^2=\max(m, 0)^2=0$, which is the least possible value of $\max(F(\bar{x}), 0)^2$ over the whole space. Hence $x_0$ is a feasible and global minimizer.

If $F(x_0)=m\ge0$, then $F(\bar{x})\ge F(x_0)\ge0$ for every $\bar{x}\in D=\{\bar{x}: A\bar{x}\le b\}$. Hence $\max(F(\bar{x}), 0) = F(\bar{x})\ge0$ for every $\bar{x}\in D$. Therefore
$$\min_{\bar{x}\in D} \max(F(\bar{x}), 0)^2
= \min_{\bar{x}\in D} F(\bar{x})^2
= \left(\min_{\bar{x}\in D} F(\bar{x})\right)^2 = m^2 = \max(m,0)^2.$$

Comment: Yes, that's right. I apologize for being not enough specific. Please, see the edited question.